# For Statement Not Being Executed

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a bit puzzled as to why this isn't executing properly.

```
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
    int[] XArray = new int [10000];
    int[] YArray = new int [10000];
```

The variables are initialized as public.

```
public void timeInterval(){
    mouseX = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    mouseY = (int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
    System.out.println("mouseX and mouseY are collected");
            for(i = 0; i > XArray.length; i++){
                XArray[i] = mouseX;
                System.out.println("XArray works");
            }

            for(j= 0; j > YArray.length; j++){
                YArray[j] = mouseY;
                System.out.println("YArray works");
            }

            System.out.println("The arrays have been created properly");


    System.out.println(mouseX+"X");
    //System.out.println(mouseY+"Y");
    System.out.println(XArray[i]);
}
```

Here is the output.

```
mouseX and mouseY are collected
The arrays have been created properly
171X
0
```

The for-loops are being overlooked for some reason. I've tried to make another for-loop in the same way and that loop didn't get executed either.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help fix the for-loops so that they are executed by the compiler or give any advice on what I could have been doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < XArray.length; i++){`...

Comment: There's a big difference between `<` and `>` ;)

Comment: The second parameter is the termination expression. When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.

Comment: @user202729 this is a typo error of little use to future readers

Comment: @Reimeus The problem is people will post answers anyway...

Comment: @Reimeus I suggest only comment if (1) the question is closed (2) OP has not received an answer. (thoughts?)

Comment: @user202729 should be voted to close due to typo

Comment: @Reimeus Then? I suppose you have voted to close it as typo, but there are not yet 5 votes, and OP get answers (and even upvotes!) anyway... (this is getting a bit long, move to chat?)

Comment: @user202729 you should only answer if you think the question is legit enough not to be closed or deleted.Posting answer to such questions is not at all appreciated because they delays the deletion procedure. So if comments are enough to help the OP, answering is discouraged for questions to be closed obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops are formed of three parts, and the second part (`i > XArray.length`) is the condition that's checked each time before the loop body is executed.

```
for(i = 0; i > XArray.length; i++){
```

Here, the condition checks whether i is *greater* than the array length, which it never will be (you've just initialised it to 0, and an array length can't be negative!) So the loop never runs.

You almost certainly want to check if it's *less* than the array length instead. This would then fit the common for-loop pattern for iterating through an array.

Answer (score 0):

you have: `i > XArray.length`, I think you want `i < XArray.length`